# AWS SAM - How to override generated resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-sam

I'm trying to build a REST API with SAM. My YAML file looks like this:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: >-
  example-rest-api

Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  allEquipmentsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/myModel.getAll
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Description: example description
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: GET

  saveEquipmentFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/myModel.save
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Description: example description
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: POST

  ApplicationResourceGroup:
    Type: AWS::ResourceGroups::Group
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - ApplicationInsights-SAM-
          - Ref: AWS::StackName
      ResourceQuery:
        Type: CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0
  ApplicationInsightsMonitoring:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationInsights::Application
    Properties:
      ResourceGroupName:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - ApplicationInsights-SAM-
          - Ref: AWS::StackName
      AutoConfigurationEnabled: 'true'
    DependsOn: ApplicationResourceGroup
Outputs:
  WebEndpoint:
    Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/{Stage}"
```

As I understand it, SAM creates some resources for me in the background. For example:

```json
"ServerlessRestApi": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
      ...
```

How can I override these generated resources? I want to add API Gateway validation model. For this I need to override background generated resources. AWS Resources is not clean enough. What approach should I take if I can't override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "override" properties per se, but you can directly create resources if you need greater control.

When you specify an `Event: ApiEvent` on your function, SAM creates a `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resource for you.  As the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-generated-resources-function.html#sam-specification-generated-resources-function-api) say, you can reference the `RestApi` its Logical ID `ServerlessRestApi`.  This is helpful for passing the `RestApi` to another resource, but not configuring the `RestApi` itself.

If you need greater control over the Api properties, you should instead explicily create a [AWS::Serverless::Api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html) resource.  Configure it as required. Then pass the Api reference to your functions [event source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-eventsource.html) configuration as the `RestApiId`.

SAM is a superset of CloudFormation.  You can also include `AWS::ApiGateway::` resources directly in your SAM template if SAM's abstractions don't fit your use case.  This gives you the greatest level of control.